# Pi Zero system not seeing USB port

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, usb-audio

I’m a nooby who built a Pi Grrl Zero, and it was working fine.  I could plug my mini keyboard dongle into the USB data port and it worked.  Then I plugged in an audio adapter.  That was a mistake!  The screen went blank and when I unplugged the adapter the Pi rebooted.  After that, the port stopped working.  Running `lsusb` shows the system  is not seeing the port anymore.

I figure I may have burnt something out, but despite my research I can’t determine how to use the test pads under the port to check for continuity.  I can’t get to the top of the Pi without disassembling the entire device.

Any ideas on how or if I can restore the USB port?

Comment: "I can’t get to the top of the Pi without disassembling the entire device"

Comment: Correct.  The Pi is soldered into a sandwich with another board and it would be quite difficult to de-solder the connections and pull them apart.

Comment: How did you plug in the audio adapter (and what sort is it)?

Comment: ThANKS TO EDIT TIMeOUT YOU GOT ONLY PART OF MY POST.
(Not everybody is a fast typist so longer comments have to be edited off line ) 

To my knowledge  +5V power input to Zero is “raw” - not going thru regulator or any protective device This power bus is directly connected to USB power pins, again no protection. 
Since you can do “lsusb” you Pi Zero is still functioning, but how do you communicate with it ?
If via USB port , it still has power. 

So how is your “GRRL “ powered?

Comment: 1. Audio adapter- it's a generic USB adapter with male USB plug on one side and female 3.5 " audio and microphone jacks on the other.  It is un-powered.  The Pi 0 USB is a mini port, so an adapter is used to size it up to standard size.  The port adapter checks out OK on another Pi 0 I have.  It is not the problem.

Comment: 2.  The Pi Grrl Zero is battery powered.  See this website for full description https://learn.adafruit.com/pigrrl-zero/overview I can communicate with the Pi by SSH.

Comment: 3. How do I communicate with it?  Using SSH.  Output of the lsusb is: Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub.  So the Pi is not seeing the USB data port.

Comment: 4.  You seem to be referring to the USB the Pi 0 uses for power (but no data).  I'm referring to the second USB port on the board. I know that the Pi is still functioning.  My question is, how can I restore function to the USB port?

Answer (score 1):

The test pads are wired [as follows](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1184875).

[image]

Or in more detail from [here](https://www.sudomod.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2627):
[image]

I'm not sure how directly the 5V from the Pi's power in links to the USB port though - ao the USB device may have power but one of the other lines may have issues (the Pi0 doesn't have a polyfuse etc for current surges)!

Test pad designations can be found [here](http://hackers.gallery/841/misc/raspberry-pi-zero-pad-probing), they apparently are similar to the B+ in some ways. To use them get a voltmeter, and you can test the resistances between pins (CAREFULLY), or but checking if they are producing the correct voltages (e.g. between PP1 and ground should be 5 volts).

In software you can also examine `dmesg -w` to see if anything happens upon trying the USB port

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have found the test pad designations and so forth, but this is where my lack of experience comes in.  I assume that those test pads are there to test for continuity between the USB pins and some other spots on the board, but I don't know where to check.  I have tried using an undamaged pi 0 and testing continuity between the pad for each data lead and every other pad or hole on the back of the board, but found no continuity anywhere.  Yet that USB functions perfectly.  I have tried dmesg -w, but I don't really understand what I'm looking for.